# Linux connect to OpenVPN but leave a separate local connection

Tags: networking, debian, openvpn

I'm trying to create a Debian server where one connection is to an OpenVPN VPN and another is direct. I've got a VPS in the cloud but it's only got a single Ethernet NIC (does that matter?). I'm only using the VPN connection to backup the VPS drives to my SMB drives, and I want everything else to go thru a non-tunneled connection.

How can I do this?

Is there a way I can direct which internet interface a command on the terminal goes through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally called [split routing](https://openvpn.net/for/split-tunneling-with-access-server/).

You'd have to set up a routing table, telling your operating system that the backup target is reachable over VPN, and the rest of the internet is reachable via some other means.

Comment: I'll look into this

Comment: Thanks. I used `route no-pull` in my client.conf file which meant that routes were not pulled from the server. Then I explicitly defined my routes, of which I only defined my LAN, so the rest would go through normally. Thanks again